# Initialize String array with Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, string

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 String s = sc.next();`

Where I want my string to be 'This is a string'
When I print it only return 'This' if suppose i gave the above input because I've used space. 
So what I have to do in such a way that I should not use for loop to initialize such a string.

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Did you use `nextInt` or other `nextXXX` method before it?

Comment: `import java.util.*;
class A{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int t= sc.nextInt();
  for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
   String s =sc.nextLine();
   System.out.print(s);
   
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Related [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo ! It solved my issue

Comment: That is common problem which everyone faced at least once :) To simplify it: when scanner is asking you for data and you do `123[enterKey]` you are putting into stream characters `123\r\n` (where `\r` and `\n` represent line separators). `nextInt()` doesn't consume line separators so it consumes only `123`. Now `nextLine` is suppose to return text between current position of cursor and next line separator (or end of string). Since it finds line separators right away it returns empty string which makes it look like it didn't work.